# JRE fatal error

Tags: java

I am getting following error some times in the middle of running application.What could be the reason? Here is the full exception

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007fa9b6c7cbf6, pid=13977, tid=140365014128384
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x5bf6]  readCEN+0x8e6
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fa930013000):  JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-18" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14227, stack(0x00007fa946be5000,0x00007fa946ce6000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x00007fa928f73000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000058c26f2d, RBX=0x00007fa928f72fd4, RCX=0x00007fa928f73017, RDX=0x00000000c0cc7733
RSP=0x00007fa946ce0d10, RBP=0x00007fa946ce0ed0, RSI=0xffff8056d7297000, RDI=0x00007fa928f72fe7
R8 =0x00007fa9b6c891d7, R9 =0x0000000000000008, R10=0x00000000000005ae, R11=0x00007fa9bd731610
R12=0x00007fa928f72fb8, R13=0x0000000000000005, R14=0x00007fa928f61cd7, R15=0x00007fa928f73000
RIP=0x00007fa9b6c7cbf6, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010217, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fa946ce0d10)
0x00007fa946ce0d10:   00007fa984459680 00007fa984459a58
0x00007fa946ce0d20:   00007fa946ce0e83 00007fa946ce0e82
0x00007fa946ce0d30:   00007fa946ce0e81 00007fa946ce0e80
0x00007fa946ce0d40:   00007fa946ce0e4a ffff8056d7297000
0x00007fa946ce0d50:   00007fa946ce0de0 ffffffff00000002
0x00007fa946ce0d60:   00007fa9540a08b0 000002d7b8006318
0x00007fa946ce0d70:   00007fa9540a6550 00007fa928f72fd4
0x00007fa946ce0d80:   00007fa928f72fd5 00007fa928f85d06
0x00007fa946ce0d90:   000000000021cd34 00000000001f8cd7
0x00007fa946ce0da0:   000002b2000005ae 00007fa928f85d34
0x00007fa946ce0db0:   0000003100000000 0000000000000031
0x00007fa946ce0dc0:   000000a40000005b 000000000021cd4a
0x00007fa946ce0dd0:   000000000020cccb 00007fa9540a3580
0x00007fa946ce0de0:   0000000014000060 a400000000000000
0x00007fa946ce0df0:   54454d001f634381 494c2f464e492d41
0x00007fa946ce0e00:   78742e45534e4543 0a031402014b5074
0x00007fa946ce0e10:   ea59860008080000 000d6b6cb3bb9742
0x00007fa946ce0e20:   0000130000251000 0000000000000000
0x00007fa946ce0e30:   4d001f7f3b81a400 2f464e492d415445
0x00007fa946ce0e40:   742e454349544f4e 000006054b507478
0x00007fa946ce0e50:   405d05ae05ae0000 0000001f8cd70002
0x00007fa946ce0e60:   0000000006054b50 0002405d05ae05ae
0x00007fa946ce0e70:   00000000001f8cd7 00000000000000a4
0x00007fa946ce0e80:   0000000000000001 00007fa9540a08b0
0x00007fa946ce0e90:   00007fa946ce0eb0 00007fa9bdd96d39
0x00007fa946ce0ea0:   0000000000000000 00007fa9540a08b0
0x00007fa946ce0eb0:   00007fa946ce0ef0 00000000000000a4
0x00007fa946ce0ec0:   0000000000000001 00007fa9540a08b0
0x00007fa946ce0ed0:   00007fa946ce1020 00007fa9b6c7d1e4
0x00007fa946ce0ee0:   00000141320cf908 00007fa946ce1050
0x00007fa946ce0ef0:   00007fa904034b50 00007fa95409f7d0
0x00007fa946ce0f00:   0000000000000001 00007fa9b8065b10 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fa9b6c7cbf6)
0x00007fa9b6c7cbd6:   ff 49 8d 04 34 48 89 42 08 8b 85 e4 fe ff ff 31
0x00007fa9b6c7cbe6:   d2 83 e8 01 49 8d 4c 04 2f 89 d0 c1 e0 05 29 d0
0x00007fa9b6c7cbf6:   41 0f be 17 49 83 c7 01 49 39 cf 8d 14 10 75 e9
0x00007fa9b6c7cc06:   89 d0 89 d6 31 d2 f7 b5 9c fe ff ff 89 d2 48 c1 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000058c26f2d is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fa928f72fd4 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00007fa928f73017 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000c0cc7733 is pointing into object: 0x00000000c0cc75e8
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
RSP=0x00007fa946ce0d10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fa930013000
RBP=0x00007fa946ce0ed0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fa930013000
RSI=0xffff8056d7297000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007fa928f72fe7 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007fa9b6c891d7: <offset 0x121d7> in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so at 0x00007fa9b6c77000
R9 =0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000000005ae is an unknown value
R11=0x00007fa9bd731610: <offset 0x184610> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007fa9bd5ad000
R12=0x00007fa928f72fb8 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000005 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007fa928f61cd7 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007fa928f73000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007fa946be5000,0x00007fa946ce6000],  sp=0x00007fa946ce0d10,  free space=1007k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libzip.so+0x5bf6]  readCEN+0x8e6
C  [libzip.so+0x61e4]  ZIP_Put_In_Cache0+0x124
C  [libzip.so+0x4045]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_open+0xe5
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Ljava/lang/String;IJZ)J+0
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Ljava/io/File;ILjava/nio/charset/Charset;)V+148

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Ljava/lang/String;IJZ)J+0
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Ljava/io/File;ILjava/nio/charset/Charset;)V+148
J  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/catalina/loader/ResourceEntry;
j  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+84
J  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
j  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+451
J  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.createJavacError(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/jasper/compiler/Node$Nodes;Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;ILorg/apache/jasper/JspCompilationContext;)Lorg/apache/jasper/compiler/JavacErrorDetail;+36
j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(Ljava/lang/Exception;)Lorg/apache/jasper/JasperException;+116
j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Z)V+434
j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;Z)V+134
j  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+435
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+446
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+393
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Lorg/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher$State;)V+98
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+338
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+243
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+84
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+222
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExecutionChain;Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;Ljava/lang/Exception;)V+98
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+421
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+319
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+72
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+32
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+446
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+68
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/springframework/security/web/FilterInvocation;)V+87
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+15
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+258
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+17
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+32
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+54
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+28
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+149
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+165
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+192
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+142
j  org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+40
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Ljavax/servlet/Filter;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+5
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+83
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+783
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+166
j  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+363
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+148
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+196
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+537
j  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+158
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+106
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fa940290000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][generic][T#4]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15050, stack(0x00007fa9466e0000,0x00007fa9467e1000)]
  0x00007fa940111000 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14645, stack(0x00007fa929037000,0x00007fa929138000)]
  0x00007fa94016d800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14644, stack(0x00007fa9a0ae9000,0x00007fa9a0bea000)]
  0x00007fa998024800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14299, stack(0x00007fa92b8f9000,0x00007fa92b9fa000)]
  0x00007fa93c002800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14292, stack(0x00007fa944081000,0x00007fa944182000)]
  0x00007fa9a403c800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14280, stack(0x00007fa92bbfc000,0x00007fa92bcfd000)]
  0x00007fa92c566800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14273, stack(0x00007fa928d16000,0x00007fa928e17000)]
=>0x00007fa930013000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-18" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14227, stack(0x00007fa946be5000,0x00007fa946ce6000)]
  0x00007fa938003800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14195, stack(0x00007fa9470ea000,0x00007fa9471eb000)]
  0x00007fa98c001000 JavaThread "JDWP Command Reader" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14155, stack(0x00007fa92bdfe000,0x00007fa92beff000)]
  0x0000000000aaa800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14152, stack(0x00007fa92beff000,0x00007fa92c000000)]
  0x00007fa9b847f800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14140, stack(0x00007fa92b1f2000,0x00007fa92b2f3000)]
  0x00007fa96818d000 JavaThread "metrics-meter-tick-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14139, stack(0x00007fa92b2f3000,0x00007fa92b3f4000)]
  0x00007fa9401d2000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][management][T#2]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14138, stack(0x00007fa92b6f7000,0x00007fa92b7f8000)]
  0x00007fa94ce66800 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14131, stack(0x00007fa92b3f4000,0x00007fa92b4f5000)]
  0x00007fa94d3ff000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][generic][T#1]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14129, stack(0x00007fa92ad66000,0x00007fa92ae67000)]
  0x00007fa97401d800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #2}" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14128, stack(0x00007fa92ae67000,0x00007fa92af68000)]
  0x00007fa94d3fd000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_boss][T#1]{New I/O boss #18}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14127, stack(0x00007fa92af68000,0x00007fa92b069000)]
  0x00007fa94d3de000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#8]{New I/O worker #17}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14126, stack(0x00007fa92b069000,0x00007fa92b16a000)]
  0x00007fa94d3bf800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#7]{New I/O worker #16}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14125, stack(0x00007fa9a044c000,0x00007fa9a054d000)]
  0x00007fa94d3a1000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#6]{New I/O worker #15}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14124, stack(0x00007fa947bfc000,0x00007fa947cfd000)]
  0x00007fa94d382800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#5]{New I/O worker #14}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14123, stack(0x00007fa9479fa000,0x00007fa947afb000)]
  0x00007fa94d364800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#4]{New I/O worker #13}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14122, stack(0x00007fa9a0700000,0x00007fa9a0801000)]
  0x00007fa94d346800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#3]{New I/O worker #12}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14121, stack(0x00007fa9a0801000,0x00007fa9a0902000)]
  0x00007fa94d329000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #11}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14120, stack(0x00007fa9478f9000,0x00007fa9479fa000)]
  0x00007fa94d303000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #10}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14119, stack(0x00007fa92b5f6000,0x00007fa92b6f7000)]
  0x00007fa94d2f5800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][scheduler][T#1]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14118, stack(0x00007fa947afb000,0x00007fa947bfc000)]
  0x00007fa94d2f3800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Reaper][[timer]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14117, stack(0x00007fa9477f8000,0x00007fa9478f9000)]
  0x00007fa9401d0800 JavaThread "New I/O client worker #1-3" [_thread_in_native, id=14116, stack(0x00007fa945fd9000,0x00007fa9460da000)]
  0x00007fa9401c0800 JavaThread "New I/O client worker #1-2" [_thread_in_native, id=14115, stack(0x00007fa9460da000,0x00007fa9461db000)]
  0x00007fa94d2da800 JavaThread "Hashed wheel timer #1" [_thread_blocked, id=14108, stack(0x00007fa9469e3000,0x00007fa946ae4000)]
  0x00007fa9401a8000 JavaThread "New I/O client worker #1-1" [_thread_in_native, id=14107, stack(0x00007fa945ed8000,0x00007fa945fd9000)]
  0x00007fa94d249000 JavaThread "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14105, stack(0x00007fa9a05ff000,0x00007fa9a0700000)]
  0x00007fa94d231800 JavaThread "ExpirationStoreCache-87" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14104, stack(0x00007fa9462dc000,0x00007fa9463dd000)]
  0x00007fa97400b800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][generic][T#1]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14100, stack(0x00007fa9a034b000,0x00007fa9a044c000)]
  0x00007fa940083000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14099, stack(0x00007fa9463dd000,0x00007fa9464de000)]
  0x00007fa94d113000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][management][T#1]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14098, stack(0x00007fa9464de000,0x00007fa9465df000)]
  0x00007fa94d112800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_boss][T#1]{New I/O boss #9}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14097, stack(0x00007fa9467e1000,0x00007fa9468e2000)]
  0x00007fa94d110000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#8]{New I/O worker #8}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14096, stack(0x00007fa9468e2000,0x00007fa9469e3000)]
  0x00007fa94d10f000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#7]{New I/O worker #7}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14095, stack(0x00007fa9a024a000,0x00007fa9a034b000)]
  0x00007fa94d10d800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#6]{New I/O worker #6}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14094, stack(0x00007fa9a0149000,0x00007fa9a024a000)]
  0x00007fa94d10c000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#5]{New I/O worker #5}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14093, stack(0x00007fa9461db000,0x00007fa9462dc000)]
  0x00007fa94d10a800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#4]{New I/O worker #4}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14092, stack(0x00007fa9a0048000,0x00007fa9a0149000)]
  0x00007fa94d109800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#3]{New I/O worker #3}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14091, stack(0x00007fa947dfe000,0x00007fa947eff000)]
  0x00007fa94d0de800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #2}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14090, stack(0x00007fa947eff000,0x00007fa948000000)]
  0x00007fa94d0dd800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14089, stack(0x00007fa9465df000,0x00007fa9466e0000)]
  0x00007fa94d0da000 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][scheduler][T#1]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14088, stack(0x00007fa92b7f8000,0x00007fa92b8f9000)]
  0x00007fa94d0dc800 JavaThread "elasticsearch[Osborn, Norman][[timer]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14087, stack(0x00007fa9a0fee000,0x00007fa9a10ef000)]
  0x00007fa94c9c0000 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14086, stack(0x00007fa9a0eed000,0x00007fa9a0fee000)]
  0x00007fa940085000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-exec-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14085, stack(0x00007fa947cfd000,0x00007fa947dfe000)]
  0x00007fa938002000 JavaThread "metrics-meter-tick-thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14084, stack(0x00007fa92b4f5000,0x00007fa92b5f6000)]
  0x00007fa9b8256000 JavaThread "ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14069, stack(0x00007fa944283000,0x00007fa944384000)]
  0x00007fa9b8254000 JavaThread "ajp-bio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14068, stack(0x00007fa9a09e8000,0x00007fa9a0ae9000)]
  0x00007fa9b8252000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14066, stack(0x00007fa9a0bea000,0x00007fa9a0ceb000)]
  0x00007fa9b85d8000 JavaThread "http-bio-8084-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14065, stack(0x00007fa9a0ceb000,0x00007fa9a0dec000)]
  0x00007fa9b8250000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14064, stack(0x00007fa9a0dec000,0x00007fa9a0eed000)]
  0x00007fa96d1cf000 JavaThread "Hashed wheel timer #1" [_thread_blocked, id=14026, stack(0x00007fa946ee8000,0x00007fa946fe9000)]
  0x00007fa934004000 JavaThread "New I/O client worker #1-1" [_thread_in_native, id=14025, stack(0x00007fa946fe9000,0x00007fa9470ea000)]
  0x00007fa96cbc5800 JavaThread "metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14023, stack(0x00007fa9471eb000,0x00007fa9472ec000)]
  0x00007fa9b8568000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14000, stack(0x00007fa9a1564000,0x00007fa9a1665000)]
  0x00007fa9b80a8000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13998, stack(0x00007fa9a34f3000,0x00007fa9a35f4000)]
  0x00007fa9b80a6000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13997, stack(0x00007fa9a35f4000,0x00007fa9a36f5000)]
  0x00007fa9b80a3000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13996, stack(0x00007fa9a36f5000,0x00007fa9a37f6000)]
  0x00007fa9b80a0800 JavaThread "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13995, stack(0x00007fa9a37f6000,0x00007fa9a38f7000)]
  0x00007fa9b809d000 JavaThread "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13994, stack(0x00007fa9a38f7000,0x00007fa9a39f8000)]
  0x00007fa9b8088000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13993, stack(0x00007fa9a3bfc000,0x00007fa9a3cfd000)]
  0x00007fa9b8072800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13992, stack(0x00007fa9a3cfd000,0x00007fa9a3dfe000)]
  0x00007fa9b806e800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13991, stack(0x00007fa9a3dfe000,0x00007fa9a3eff000)]
  0x00007fa9b800c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=13981, stack(0x00007fa9be0a8000,0x00007fa9be1a9000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007fa9b806c000 VMThread [stack: 0x00007fa9a3eff000,0x00007fa9a4000000] [id=13990]
  0x00007fa9b80b2800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007fa9a33f2000,0x00007fa9a34f3000] [id=13999]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 240640K, used 192461K [0x00000000ec100000, 0x00000000ffc00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 222208K, 78% used [0x00000000ec100000,0x00000000f6b01448,0x00000000f9a00000)
  from space 18432K, 99% used [0x00000000f9a00000,0x00000000fabf2068,0x00000000fac00000)
  to   space 50176K, 0% used [0x00000000fcb00000,0x00000000fcb00000,0x00000000ffc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 111616K, used 80946K [0x00000000c4400000, 0x00000000cb100000, 0x00000000ec100000)
  object space 111616K, 72% used [0x00000000c4400000,0x00000000c930cbe0,0x00000000cb100000)
 PSPermGen       total 79360K, used 78781K [0x00000000bf200000, 0x00000000c3f80000, 0x00000000c4400000)
  object space 79360K, 99% used [0x00000000bf200000,0x00000000c3eef4d8,0x00000000c3f80000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00007fa9b3a6f000,0x00007fa9b3c77000] byte_map_base: 0x00007fa9b3476000

Polling page: 0x00007fa9be1c4000

Code Cache  [0x00007fa9b3c77000, 0x00007fa9b42e7000, 0x00007fa9b6c77000)
 total_blobs=1954 nmethods=1377 adapters=537 free_code_cache=42692Kb largest_free_block=43610752
```

Comment: seems to happen at the time of opening some `zip` file.

Comment: Try updating to the latest JRE (you're running update 51, update 60 is the newest.)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405641/jvm-crashes-at-libzip-so

Comment: A suggestion: check any libraries that are deployed with the application or you manually added to tomcat to be sure they're not zero bytes in size; judging from the stacktrace its the Java compiler failing due to a zip file not being loaded properly which most likely refers to a jar dependency file.

Comment: but its happening sometimes.how will i know which jar is causing problem from this trace